# Pig Script Function Question

Tags: function, apache-pig

As can be seen in the following Pig code, I am repeating a set of statements for Attr1 and Attr2. Is there a way to extract it out in a function? Code samples would really help.

```
Attr1ValidRecs = FILTER BaseRecs BY Attr1 IS NOT NULL;
Attr1ValidRecs_all = GROUP Attr1ValidRecs ALL;
Attr1Count = FOREACH Attr1ValidRecs_all GENERATE COUNT(Attr1ValidRecs);
Attr1CountStr = FOREACH Attr1Count GENERATE CONCAT('Recs with Attr1 not null : ',(chararray)$0);

Attr1BaseCross = CROSS BaseRecsCount,Attr1Count;
Attr1BaseRatio = FOREACH Attr1BaseCross GENERATE CONCAT('Ratio of Not Null Attr1 to Total Base Recs: ',(chararray)((double)$1/(double)$0));

Attr2ValidRecs = FILTER BaseRecs BY Attr2 IS NOT NULL;
Attr2ValidRecs_all = GROUP Attr2ValidRecs ALL;
Attr2Count = FOREACH Attr2ValidRecs_all GENERATE COUNT(Attr2ValidRecs);
Attr2CountStr = FOREACH Attr2Count GENERATE CONCAT('Recs with Attr2 not null : ',(chararray)$0);

Attr2BaseCross = CROSS BaseRecsCount,Attr2Count;
Attr2BaseRatio = FOREACH Attr2BaseCross GENERATE CONCAT('Ratio of Not Null Attr2 to Total Base Recs:
',(chararray)((double)$1/(double)$0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace multiple rows into a batch of Pig operations, unfortunately. This is something I wish I could do sometimes, so I sympathize.

What I've done in the past when I have something I repeat over and over in the same script is to generate the Pig Latin code in a Python script (or whatever, obviously) with a for loop, replacing certain key words. This still feels pretty dirty, though.